# Dask read_parquet adds an extra column dir0

Tags: python, dask, parquet

I have a multiple parquet files in difference directories

```
paths = ['adl://entrofi/shift/20190725_060500_20190928_060500/*.parquet',
'adl://entrofi/shift/20190726_060500_20190928_060500/*.parquet',
'adl://entrofi/shift/20190727_060500_20190928_060500/*.parquet',
'adl://entrofi/shift/20190728_060500_20190928_060500/*.parquet',
'adl://entrofi/shift/20190820_060500_20190920_060500/*.parquet',
'adl://entrofi/shift/20190828_060500_20190928_060500/*.parquet']
```

Each file contains columns `A,B,C`

I wanna read all this files so I do a

`ddf = dd.read_parquet(paths).drop_duplicates()`

However, `ddf` contains columns `A,B, C and dir0`. `dir0` contains names of the folders 
from which each path in `paths` was read.

Reading each individual file in `paths` contains no `dir0` columns.

How do I avoid the addition of `dir0` automatically to my `ddf`?

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behaviour with the fastparquet backend, because it looks like your files are partitioned by folder-name, in this case using the "drill" scheme (as opposed to `field=value` directory names).

To avoid it, you could use the pyarrow engine, or simply specify the columns that you would like to keep:

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(paths, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
ddf = dd.read_parquet(paths, engine='pyarrow')
```

Comment: I could specify the columns but it makes the code clumsy since I have a lot of columns. When I specify `pyarrow`, another error pops up `NotImplementedError: Using pyarrow with a 'DaskAdlFileSystem' filesystem object`

Comment: For the latter, I think you will need to wait for upcoming releases.